# Can't to reduce two jQuery functions into one function

Tags: jquery, function, reduce

I can not fully think how to reduce two almost identical, init listeners, jQuery functions into one.

**VARIANT 1 (the workable).**
*Variant **№1** is working, but it's look like something bad:*

```
// Checkbox
var matchesWithEmail = document.getElementById('matchesWithEmail');
// Checkbox
var matchesWithEmail2 = document.getElementById('matchesWithEmail-2');

jQuery(matchesWithEmail).on('change', function (e) {
    var current = e.target;
    var checked = current.checked;

    matchesWithEmail2.checked = checked;
});

jQuery(matchesWithEmail2).on('change', function (e) {
    var current = e.target;
    var checked = current.checked;

    matchesWithEmail.checked = checked;
});
```

**VARIANT 2 (not fully workable).**
*I also was trying to reduce it, but it I had recieve bad idea result, it gives wrong working sometimes:*

```
var matchesWithEmail = [document.getElementById('matchesWithEmail'), document.getElementById('matchesWithEmail-2')];
matchesWithEmail.forEach(function (element) {
    jQuery(element).on('change', function (e) {
        var current = e.target,
            checked = current.checked,
            allExceptCurrent = matchesWithEmail.filter(function (element) {
                return element !== current;
            });

        allExceptCurrent.forEach(function (element) {
            jQuery(element).off('change');

            element.checked = checked;
            jQuery(element).on('change', function (e) {
                var current2 = e.target,
                    checked2 = current2.checked,
                    allExceptCurrent2 = matchesWithEmail.filter(function (element) {
                        return element !== current2;
                    });
                allExceptCurrent2.forEach(function (element) {
                    jQuery(element).off('change');
                    element.checked = checked2;
                });
            });
        });
    });
});
```

Please tell of how compactly this two functions reducing?

Comment: hmm not sure I understand, you want to keep both? or just one? and you'd like us to review your code and give you idea's on how to improve it?

Comment: what do you mean by "reduce it"? combining the two into one? Add a description on what you're trying to accomplish might help.

Comment: Yeah i was trying to improve it, because my variant is bad, i know it but unexpectedly I could not come up with a nice solution. Untill yet **jfriend00** offered an elegant solution.I can not understand why had not thought of it by myself. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can refer to `this` to reference the object that created the event and get its property.  That means you can then do this:

```
var matches = jQuery("#matchesWithEmail, #matchesWithEmail-2");
matches.on('change', function(e) {
    // set both objects to have the checked value from the one that just changed
    matches.prop("checked", this.checked);
});
```

This does the following:

1. Creates a single jQuery object that refers to both matches objects.
2. Registers an event handler for the 'change' event on both objects.
3. When that event fires, it makes sure that both objects have their `checked` property set to what the one is set to that just changed (so both objects will track each other).
4. In the interest of simplification, this just sets the `checked` property for both objects even though the current one does not have to be set.  You could filter out the `this` object using `.not(this)`, but there really is no point.  For example, you could do this:

Code:

```
var matches = jQuery("#matchesWithEmail, #matchesWithEmail-2");
matches.on('change', function(e) {
    matches.not(this).prop("checked", this.checked);
});
```